# Can't boot OS installed in UEFI mode

Tags: linux, boot, uefi, bios

My laptop is an **Acer Aspire e15 Start**.

The laptop BIOS has two boot modes: **UEFI or Legacy**.

When I install any operating system (either Linux or Windows) in **UEFI**, at the end of the installation and restart the computer, I get this message: (This didn't happen before)

```
Default Boot Device Missing or Boot Failed.
Insert Recovery Media and Hit any key
Then Select 'Boot Manager' to choose a new Boot
Device or to Boot Recovery Media
```

When I install any operating system (either Linux or Windows) in **Legacy**, when I finish the installation and restart the computer, the operating system loads perfectly.

**I don't want to have the BIOS on Legacy as it looks pretty lousy.**

One day I took it to a computer store so that they could fix it for me (which wasn't cheap) and today, when starting the computer in **UEFI** (More than anything to test if I can install the operating system in that mode) , I can see that in the BIOS there is a file called **"EFI File Boot 0"** that I don't know how it works.

**I would like to reinstall the linux I had before in UEFI.**

Comment: Which OS exactly you have installed now that doesn't boot? What options do you have at UEFI settings > Boot menu > OS selection (or similar)?

Comment: I have installed Debian latest version. But anyway, it doesn't load with any OS. I mean, I've tried every OS but it doesn't work. And then about boot menu. When I install the OS, this one shows the error message. I can't choose anything, just reboot the computer. In BIOS, I've the boot mode, the secure boot and the boot order

Comment: My question is about the boot order and/or OS selection. What *exactly* are the options there? Keep in mind that often those are distinct settings. "Order" refers to drive order and if multiple drives then the one where the ESP resides should have priority. Then there's "OS selection" (or something similar" where user select among the bootloaders in the ESP (e.g. Debian, Windows bootloader manager).

Comment: You can try this tool https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair . Please use the 2nd option (temp install in a live session), DON'T apply any fix but generate the report and then [edit] the question and post the link here.

Comment: Ordered they are as follows:
- EFI boot file 0: Debian
- My hard drive
- USB Stick

Comment: Many Acer models required "trust" on Ubuntu entry. It would be shown as "unknown" in UEFI boot menu. And you must be running the newest UEFI firmware. Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot